# esri ELG geosearch is not working properly

Tags: leaflet, maps, esri, esri-leaflet

If you take a look at this : https://codesandbox.io/s/2wy7v2orwr?file=/src/Map.js

you will see you can search things on the map, but if you zoom-in somewhere randomly(deep zoom in, for example somewhere in the ocean), the search is unresponsive , i.e. it doesnt give any results in the result dropdown. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [useMapBounds](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/controls/geosearch.html#options) option to false when you create the geocoder.

May I also suggest you try [react-esri-leaflet](https://github.com/slutske22/react-esri-leaflet), which has a ready made esri-leaflet geocoder component for react-leaflet.